# Publish a post in a specific language with i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have a postgresql database created with rails and implemented i18n to get two versions of my website: mywebsite.com/en/ and mywebsite.com/fr/. Whithin this website, I have created a form linked to a table made of a title (string) and a text (string).

When I create a post, I would like to choose whether to publish it in the /en/ section or the /fr/ section (something like /en/posts/1 and /fr/posts/1).

I was thinking of creating a category called "language", to add has_many :language in the Post model and to select which language to publish in through the form. However I struggle to implement it, would you have suggestions ?

Comment: What are you having trouble with? model? routes?

Comment: Can you show us some starting code that you have so far. I think you could add the i18n params into a field for the post and than check which param has been saved to that post. But I dont know if it is a good solution for you